# Como fazer a injeção de dependência em uma classe criada dinamicamente?

Tags: c#, asp.net, injeção-de-dependência

Estou fazendo um gateway para um projeto  cliente consumir microserviços. Nesse gateway, a forma de que o cliente vai consumir a aplicação é através de uma interface. A implementação dessa interface vai ser criada de forma dinâmica (Em tempo de compilação). Por isso preciso saber como injetar a dependência de classe gerada dinamicamente. Exemplo:

```
[MicroServiceHost("MsProduct")]
public interface IProductService
{

    [MicroService("GetAllProducts")]
    IRestResponse GetAllProducts(List<KeyValuePair<object, object>> parameters = null);


    [MicroService("AddProduct")]
    IRestResponse AddProduct(List<KeyValuePair<object, object>> parameters = null);
}

public class MsProductController : Controller
{
    IProductService _productService;

    public MsProductController(IProductService productService)
    {
        _productService = productService;
    }

    public ActionResult GetAll()
    {
        var request = _productService.GetAllProducts();
        var r = request.Content;

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, either ask this question on SO-EN or translate this question to Portuguese. tyvm

Comment: Sua pergunta é muito ampla, seria legal colocar o código desta classe...
Recomendo a leitura: https://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-a-injecao-de-dependencia-no-asp-net-mvc/27099

Comment: Eu não entendi, você quer implementar injeção de dependencia em um projeto seu? É isso? Eu também acho que a pergunta não tem nada haver com "microserviços"

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Acho que ele quer "injetar a dependência" numa instância (objeto) criada via reflection. Confere, GuilhermeRamos?

Comment: Considerando que seja esta hipótese, você vai carregar o objeto a partir da mesma dll? Ou vai carregar a dll primeiro?

Comment: @LINQ foi o que imaginei, só que a tag microserviços simplesmente não fazia sentido e nem se isso tinha haver com a parte logo do "começo": cria uma "classe dinamica".

Comment: Desculpe pela forma da pergunta. Ajustando. Estou fazendo um gateway para um cliente consumir microserviços. Nesse gateway, a forma de que o cliente vai consumir a aplicação é através de uma interface. A implementação dessa interface vai ser criada de forma dinâmica (Em tempo de compilação).
Por isso preciso saber como injetar a dependência de classe gerada dinamicamente.

Comment: O [MEF](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/) não pode te ajudar neste caso?

Comment: Obrigado @GabrielHeming , deu certo. Vou escrever como resolvi e vou te atribuir os créditos !

Comment: @GuilhermeRamos Excelente! Ficarei no aguardo da implementação.

Answer (score -1):

Para que o .NET saiba qual serviço injetar no momento certo podemos utilizar um delegate que retorna a interface desejada e um discriminador que diga como escolher o serviço a ser injetado. Segue exemplo:

Delegate:

```
public delegate IPessoaService PessoaServiceResolver(TipoPessoa tipoPessoa);
```

Injeção de Controle:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddServices(this IServiceCollection builder)
{
    builder.AddScoped<PessoaFísicaService>();
    builder.AddScoped<PessoaJurídicaService>();

    builder.AddTransient<PessoaServiceResolver>(serviceProvider => tipoPessoa =>
    {
        return tipoPessoa switch
        {
            TipoPessoa.Física => serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<PessoaFísicaService>(),
            TipoPessoa.Jurídica => serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<PessoaJurídicaService>(),
            _ => default,
        };
    });

    return builder;
}
```

Para mais detalhes:

Construindo fluxos utilizando domínio abstrato e herança com .NET C#
https://medium.com/p/d4bbe92b1d45